# String and counter Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, counter

I am required to make a table that records the votes made for each painting, however I am having difficulty making the votes count for individual paintings, so if I were to answer D the vote would be recorded for A. Please help. I also need this to be an endless loop which is ended when a value say "hello" is entered.

```
public static void allo()

{   String[] painting = {"Mona Lisa","Water Lilies","The Scream","A Young Rembrandt"};
    String[] art = {"A","B","C","D"};
    int[] vote = {0,0,0,0}; 
    String searchkey ="";
    for (int i=0; i<art.length; i++)
    {
    searchkey = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please tell us which painting you thihnk is the best? \n Vote A for Mona Lisa \n Vote B for Water Lilies \n                                    Vote C for The Scream \n Vote D for A Young Rembrandt");
        if (art[i].equals(searchkey))
        {   vote[i]+=1; 
        }   
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The current votes are:\n" +vote[0]+ " : " +painting[0]+"\n"+vote[1]+" : " +painting[1]+                             "\n" +vote[2]+" : "+painting[2]+ "\n" +vote[3]+" : " +painting[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put the question and display of the answer outside the for loop I think. First ask vote, then for loop, then show result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop is in the wrong place, it should be after your dialog.  You should wrap it with a do/while loop.

```
do {
    searchkey = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please tell us which painting you thihnk is the best? \n Vote A for Mona Lisa \n Vote B for Water Lilies \n                                    Vote C for The Scream \n Vote D for A Young Rembrandt");
    for (int i=0; i<art.length; i++)
    {
        if (art[i].equals(searchkey))
        {   vote[i]=vote[i]+1; 
        }   
     }
} while (!searchkey.equals("hello"));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The current votes are:\n" +vote[0]+ " : " +painting[0]+"\n"+vote[1]+" : " +painting[1]+                             "\n" +vote[2]+" : "+painting[2]+ "\n" +vote[3]+" : " +painting[3]);
```

Comment: Im unfamiliar with the "do" command, could you explain this? Also, thank you and out of curiosity is there a way to do this without a while? I doubt it but I'd rather ask a seasoned programmer

Comment: And another thing, I would Like the question to be asked each time a vote is cast, and I would also like the votes shown each time too

Comment: you can use a for loop:  for (;;){ searchkey = showinputdialog..,  if (search key.equals("hello") break;  /* statements */}

Comment: @duldi for [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) statement check the link. What you mean *do this without a while?* Have you tested this code?

Comment: @Frakcool I just looked up the do while statement, ive only come across while before this. I'm still having somethings my codes doing wrong, but I think I can take it from here, hopefully. Thank you

Comment: @duldi `do-while` will execute the code **at least once** while the condition is true, on the other hand, `while` statement might or might not execute depending on the condition. `do-while` evaluates condition **after** it executes the code, `while` evaluates **before** it executes. Those are the main differences if it helps. If you're having errors on your code, maybe posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help.

Comment: @Frakcool That was peerfect I understand now, thank you and I'll also check the link out too